# Picking colors manually from Image in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

What I want to implement to React Native project is something like this; https://imagecolorpicker.com/en

I tried some picker libraries for automatically picking colors from image, but the results were not satisfying. So I want to provide an option to choose the colors manually from a selected image.

Is there any way/library to do it in React Native? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `canvas` doesn't exist in RN although there might be a similar representation in other libraries. Alternatively, you could load in the image, have an overlay listening for a press event to grab coordinates then find the colour based on a given x/y position on the given platform native side.

Comment: I don't get it really well, can you elaborate a bit?